# Question about aggregated data and the effect on specific contributors

Tags: time-series, aggregation, generalized-additive-model

I have a set of data about the incidence of certain types of infections that occur in hospitals. The analysis has looked at the incidence trend for all aggregated results in a time series. This uses a GAM fitted spline to identify the incidence trend for aggregated data.

Over the past year the incidence trend has increased sharply for the aggregated data set. The corresponding incidence trends for each participating hospital do not look much different.

Is there a way to test a hypothesis that a specific individual hospital or hospitals drive the increase in the aggregated incidence?

Comment: Possibly too simple a check - have you looked at your hospitals with higher incidence rates to see if the patient counts have increased more (as a proportion) for those hospitals compared to hospitals with lower infection rates? If your hospitals with higher rates are contributing proportionately more data over time, that would explain the overall rate, even though the incidence in each hospital would remain the same. All I can think is that the individual hospital contributions to the data are not remaining constant over time.